# The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to execute a script in my template using Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts, but also I'm trying to declare de user assigned identity in the same template

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
    "name": "scriptIdentity",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
    "apiVersion": "2019-10-01-preview",
    "name": "updateAppServiceConfigMountPointScript",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', parameters('appservice_name'), 'web')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', parameters('storageAccounts_name'), 'default')]"
    ],
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
    "identity": {
        "type": "userAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity'), '2019-08-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
            "clientId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity'), '2019-08-01', 'full').identity.clientId]"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "environmentVariables": [
            {
                "name": "account_name",
                "value": "[parameters('storageAccounts_name')]"
            },
            {
                "name": "app_name",
                "value": "[parameters('appservice_name')]"
            },
            {
                "name": "resource_group_name",
                "value": "[resourceGroup().name]"
            }
            
        ],
        "scriptContent": "$access_key = ((az storage account keys list --account-name $account_name) | ConvertFrom-JSON).value[0]; az webapp config storage-account add --name \\\"$app_name\\\" --resource-group \\\"$resource_group_name\\\" --custom-id \\\"frontend\\\" --storage-type \\\"AzureBlob\\\" --account-name \\\"stelckstorageaccount\\\" --share-name \\\"frontend\\\" --mount-path \\\"/home/site/wwwroot/frontend\\\" --access-key \\\"$access_key\\\"",
        "timeout": "PT1M",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess"
    }
```

The template fails in this part:

```
"userAssignedIdentities": {
    "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity'), '2019-08-01', 'full').identity.principalId]",
    "clientId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity'), '2019-08-01', 'full').identity.clientId]"
}
```

With the following error:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'updateAppServiceConfigMountPointScript' at line '930' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'reference' is not expected at this location. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

**How can I reference the assigned identity in the deploymentscript without the reference function?**

*RELATED: ['Microsoft.Web/sites/config' azureStorageAccounts fails due to 500 InternalError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64877968/microsoft-web-sites-config-azurestorageaccounts-fails-due-to-500-internalerror)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the resourceId of the identity, e.g.

```
"userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'scriptIdentity')]": {}
}
```

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-deployment-script-ssh-key-gen/azuredeploy.json for a full sample.

Comment: What does the comment `/*ttk bug*/` in the sample ARM template mean, especially since it involved this particular setting?

Comment: It works! Thanks for the answer. Now I have problems about permissions of the identity over the resources but I'll figure that out later. Again thanks!!

Comment: The /*ttk bug*/ is a comment that https://aka.ms/arm-ttk will flag it as an error but it's a bug in the ttk.  Re: perms, if you are assigning the role and using it in the same template it's possible that the replication of the role is not complete by the time you need to use it.  we are working on allowing the deploymentScript to run under user creds which will remove the need for the MSI and that particular problem... if you're seeing something different, post back and we can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in a Bicep template, and struggled to figure out how to implement bmoore-msft's answer. While it's not an answer to the original question, I'll post it here in case others like me stumble across this page.

The trick was to use string interpolation to get the identity id on the left side of the colon

```
identity: {
  type: 'UserAssigned'
  userAssignedIdentities: {
    '${scriptIdentity.id}': {}
  }
}
```